# Need to modify browser action popup contents upon tab change

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need to modify the contents of browser Action popup on tab change.
I am detecting change of tab in background.js script

```
var tabHandler={
    processChange:function(tab){

        var parser = document.createElement('a');//To extract the hostname, we create dom element 
        parser.href = tab.url;

        var regex=/^(www\.)?([^\.]+)/
        var matches=regex.exec(parser.hostname)//This gives us the hostname, we extract the website name
        var website=matches[2];
        function getWebsiteCoupons(site){
            var coupons=cache.pull(site)
            if(!coupons){
                couponfetcher(site)
                coupons=cache.pull(site);
            }
            return coupons;

        }
        var coupons=getWebsiteCoupons(website);
        //NEED TO UPDATE THE POPUP HERE

        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:coupons.coupons.length+coupons.deals.length+""})

    },

    onTabUpdate:function(tabId,  changeInfo,  dtab){

        chrome.tabs.get(tabId,tabHandler.processChange);


    },
    tabChanged:function(activeInfo) {

        console.log(this)   ;   
        chrome.tabs.get(activeInfo.tabId,tabHandler.processChange);
    },

    init:function(){
        chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(this.tabChanged);

    }



}

tabHandler.init();
```

So I tried to detect a click action on the browser action, but this doesn't work when I have a popup already defined.

```
function BrowserActionClicked(tab){
    alert("hello");
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(BrowserActionClicked)
```

If I remove the popup from manifest, the script works. But I don't know how to get instance of the manifest's contents

I also tried getting the views. The view however is an empty view, doesn't contain the contents of the popup.

```
var view=chrome.extension.getViews();
$(view.document).append("Hello");
```

this didn't work either. How do I update the contents of the browser popup from background script?

I am in a bit of a fix here, to be honest